# I can not make my site menu mobile friendly

Tags: php, smarty

I have a Livecart Site. [Here](http://iseeglasses.com/) it is  I have done all the responsive job for mobile but I can't make the menu mobile friendly. If you visit in mobile you can see a mobile menu but its static.

How can I have the dynamic menu on the Homepage(Left Menu) to be shown on mobile site?

Comment: Try to show only main menu items.

Comment: I cant..thats why I need help

Comment: put display: none on your all sub menu's when in mobile view

Comment: "Any one can help me out?" is not a question, not even with the question mark behind it.

Comment: re-modify site with `bootstrap` or use `media query`

Comment: You said the site is responsive. But it isn't...